# reactjs - how to render the component only once based on the props value

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have this props `this.props.isCsvHeadersColumnMismatch` coming from `rootReducer.js`. I am trying to show an error modal based on the value of this props flag.

```
render = () => {
const csvColumnMismatchError =
  this.props.csvColumnMismatch ?
    Modal.error({
      title: 'Error',
      content: 'Sorry, CSV columns does not match with the recorded columns.',
    }) : null;

return (
    <Modal
        visible={this.props.isCsvUploadModalVisible}
        okText= {this.csvColumnMismatch}
        title="CSV Upload"
        onOk={() => this.props.handleCsvUpload(
            appendOverrideFlag,
            csvHeaders,
            csvDescription,
        )}
        onCancel={this.resetModal}
        zIndex={10}
    >
        { csvColumnMismatchError }

        // have other fields of modal here after.
    </Modal>
);
}
```

With this code, am getting error as the component gets rendered multiple times and every time it pops up the error modal. I know this is not the right way to achieve the desired result. Please help!

Comment: You are doing nothing with `this.props.isCsvHeadersColumnMismatch` in your render. Maybe you meant `this.props.csvColumnMismatch` ?

Comment: What is your purpose of using `Modal.error()` function?

Comment: paste here the entire component content please